# reading and indenting a xml file perl

Tags: perl

I have the following `Perl` code, which reads the input and indents the file correctly. I'm not using `xmllint`, or `XML-Tidy` because of some problems with the `DTD`. But let's say for exercise I've use the code below:

```
 ### begin_: file metadata
        ### <region-file_info>
        ### main:
        ###   - name    : XMLPrettyPrint: simple xml pretty print in perl
        ###     desc    : use perl with XML::Twig library to print indented xml
        ###     date    : created="Thu 2005-12-01 11:08:15"
        ###     last    : lastmod="Thu 2005-12-01 11:22:34"
        ###     lang    : perl
        ###     tags    : perl xml indent formatted pretty string cfPrettyPrint
        ### </region-file_info>

### begin_: init perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use XML::Twig;

### begin_: init vars
    my  $sXML  = join "", (<DATA>);

    ### init params
    my  $params = [qw(none nsgmls nice indented record record_c)];
    my  $sPrettyFormat  = $params->[3] || 'none';

### begin_: process
    my  $twig= new XML::Twig;
    $twig->set_indent(" "x2);
    $twig->parse( $sXML );
    $twig->set_pretty_print( $sPrettyFormat );
    $sXML      = $twig->sprint;

### begin_: output
    print $sXML;

### begin_: sample data
    1;
    __END__
<table><tr age="35" >
<fname>Homer</fname>
<lname>Simpson</lname></tr>
<tr age="33" >
<fname>Barney</fname>
<lname>Rubble</lname></tr>
<tr age="29" >
<fname>Betty</fname>
<lname>Rubble</lname></tr></table>
```

It indents and print is correctly ... however, I needed to read it from an `XML` file, indent and then right it back to the same file, with the new format. I'm totally new to `Perl`, how could I read the input from a file, instead of a sample data, and then use that above code to indent?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
my $file= $ARGV[0];
XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented')
         ->parsefile( $file )
         ->print_to_file( $file);
```

No need to set the indent to 2 spaces, that's the default. The 1 at the end is also not needed, it is only needed for modules, to inform the parser that they have loaded properly.

This is also equivalent to `xml_pp -i myfile.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to read and write whole files is probably the module `File::Slurp`. It makes it as easy as this:

```
use File::Slurp;
my $content = read_file('some_file.xml');
# do stuff
write_file('some_file.xml', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

[XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) is what you need. It doesn't care about DTDs. It can read and write your XML and indent it as well.

Comment: For who comes here from their future, the docs say now "You really don't want to use this module in new code. If you ignore this warning and use it anyway, the qw(:strict) mode will save you a little pain."

Answer (score 0):

See [open](http://p3rl.org/open) for details:

```
open my $XML, '<', $filename or die $!;
my $sXML  = join "", (<$XML>);
close $XML;

# ...

open my $OUT, '>', 'file.xml' or die $!;
print {$OUT} $sXML;
close $OUT;
```